# ¿Por qué el "caldo de gallina" es un tabaco de picadura poco elaborado?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones, españa

El DLE recoge, dentro del artículo [**caldo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6lMDpXZ), la expresión **caldo de gallina** que define como

> 1. m. Esp. Tabaco de picadura poco elaborado.

¿De dónde viene esa expresión? ¿Se sigue utilizando?

Comment: Un trocito de información: `"Como era antes el Ideales, popularmente llamado "caldo de gallina" (me gustaría saber porqué), o la auténtica Picadura selecta." - Había dos clases de Ideales, uno con el papel blanco y otro con el papel amarillento; era al amarillo al que decían caldo de gallina.` https://www.relojes-especiales.com/foros/estilo-de-vida-y-tendencias-de-moda/fumado-clasico-solo-para-mayores-de-edad-83429/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos razones propuestas:

> El caso era fumar. Los domingos sacábamos el *cuarterón* (paquete de tabaco
>   picado) o la *cajetilla* (la mitad de un cuarterón) y, si los había, unos *ideales* extra. **A estos cigarrillos se les llamaba “caldo de gallina”, porque eran de más calidad que los otros y sentaban como un caldo de ave en tiempos de
>   tanto sacrificio.**
>
> - [*Tabaquismo durante la Guerra Civil Española (1936-1939)*](http://www.bvsde.paho.org/bvsacd/cd37/pt41p37.pdf), M. Cortés Blanco

---

> En los años de la Guerra Civil escaseaba el tabaco, pero también en la posguerra, había fumadores empedernidos que llegaban a intercambiar vales de racionamiento de comida por unos perreros  (un tipo especial de cigarro), y muchos trataron de sustituir el tabaco por distintas plantas que se pudieran fumar: hojas de salvia, de higuera, de patata, pámpana de la vid... otros recogían las colillas del suelo, las desmenuzaban y volvían a liar, era un verdadero gozo disponer de un cuarterón (paquete de tabaco picado) o de la cajetilla (la mitad de un cuarterón) y, si los había, de unos Ideales, cigarrillos que venían burdamente empaquetados individualmente y había que reliar, **se les llamaba caldo de gallina por el color caldoso del papel.**
>
> - [*El tabaco que fumabamos*](http://tuche.es/el-tabaco-que-fumabamos.html)

> El tabaco de cajetilla, los ideales, o caldo de gallina. Se denominaba así por el color del papel en que venía liado, un color como el del caldo, amarillento. Era el color del papel el que le proporcionaba el nombre.
>
> - [*http://pacorivera.galiciae.com*](http://pacorivera.galiciae.com/?p=7385)

> Se les llamaba "caldo de gallina" por el color "caldoso" del papel.
>
> - [*http://www.entredosamores.es*](http://www.entredosamores.es/campo%20de%20criptana/textocriptana8.html)

[image]

Comment: Es curioso que dos de las fuentes que citas usen **color caldoso**, ya que la única acepción de **caldoso** es (http://dle.rae.es/?id=6lORIS5) "1. adj. Que tiene mucho caldo."

Comment: La primera explicación es, sin duda, la más verosimil de las dos.